# Is there a more general version of "handshakes" formula n*(n-1)/2?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I tried to solve "birthdays paradox" using the "direct way" but not the one mentioned here in one of the topics - tried my own, and as one of the solutions I figured out that there was a need to consider cases where not only couples share same birthday but maybe groups of three four five etc.

Well, there is a well known formula to count unique handshakes (unique couples) amount when we have as given n (people amount):

```
n*(n-1)/2
```

My question: Is there more general formula that I can use if I need to know how many unique groups of three, or unique groups of four, or five etc...are there for a given n
Thank you

Comment: yeah you can use the concept of subsets of n ,${ n \choose k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the number of ways to [choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $k$ people from a set of $n$ people is ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Igor ofc, no prob